# Bootstrap 4 layout with cards over header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to create simple layout with 3 cards and header. 3 cards should be all in one row, but the card in the middle should be bigger(it should have bigger height and weight than the other two) and should overlap header. By default all cards created in bs4 are equal. Should I set properties for each card? Can you help me with this? Thanks.

Here is the [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/bi6qYkjBrpx7M283j9hr?p=preview)

```
    <header role="banner" class="header-test">
  <h1>Test layout</h1>
</header>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card custom-card-style">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="card custom-center-card-style">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card custom-card-style">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function that is work very well.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
     function setHeight(column) {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        //Get all the element with class = col
        column = $(column);
        column.css('height', 'auto');
        //Loop all the column
        column.each(function() {       
            //Store the highest value
            if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = $(this).height();
            }
        });
        //Set the height
        column.height(maxHeight);
    }
     setHeight('.card');
    });
```

Comment: ok this function set column height but how can I overlap column with header?